# Mongo import using shell script not working

Tags: mongodb, bash, shell, mongodb-query

I am trying to import json using bash script but it does not seem to be working properly

The error that I am getting is:
error validating settings: incompatible options: --file and positional argument(s)

Here is the script that I am trying to run

```
importserver="localhost:27017"
username="username"
password="password"
importdb="Hotel"
collections=("Customers")

echo "Begin To Import"

for c in ${collections[@]}
do
    echo "importing $c .."
     mongoimport $importserver --db $importdb --collection $c --file "$c.json"
done

echo "Done."
```

I have tried changing params and everything. None seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close.  Need to add the `--host` parameter...

```
importserver="localhost:27017"                                                                                                             
username="username"
password="password"
importdb="Hotel"
collections=("Customers")

echo "Begin To Import"

for c in ${collections[@]}
do
    echo "importing $c .."
     mongoimport --host $importserver --db $importdb --collection $c --file "$c.json"
done

echo "Done."
```

The error message `error validating settings: incompatible options: --file and positional argument(s)` is saying there is a parameter - the host name parameter - that has no tag and therefore must be identifiable by its position, but positional arguments usually go at the end.  Rather than use a positional argument, if you add the --host it will be a named argument instead.  I think there are some gotchas about which parameters are allowed to be positional and which are allowed to be named.  I think the file can be either, but I don't think host is.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. I was missing the host.